# SQL Building time ranges from sequential columns

Tags: sql, range, common-table-expression, lag, lead

I have a table with three columns.
DAYOFWEEK, STARTTIME, and ENDTIME.
For many of the rows (sorted by STARTTIME) the STARTTIME is equal to the previous ENDTIME.  I need to create ranges where those times are concurrent.

Sample Data:

| DAYOFWEEK | STARTTIME | ENDTIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | **61200** | 62100 |
| 1 | 62100 | 63000 |
| 1 | 63000 | 63900 |
| 1 | 63900 | 64800 |
| 1 | 64800 | **65700** |
| 1 | **68800** | **69900** |
| 2 | **51000** | **52000** |

Based on the sample data I'm seeking:

| DAYOFWEEK | STARTTIME | ENDTIME |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 61200 | 65700 |
| 1 | 68800 | 69900 |
| 2 | 51000 | 52000 |

I'm sure it can be done somehow with CTE's and/or LAG/LEAD but I just can't work it out.  Any brilliant ideas out there?  I'm limited to using SQL 2014.
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, then the previous did *not* work, and was therefore less than quick.

You want to partition by the day of the week, but, if a previous end time overlaps the current start time, you want to start the partition anew.

This requires grouping/partitioning your data by a value that is not contained in your data: you need to *sessionise* your data. Except in Vertica, you do that by adding a counter in one OLAP query that is at 1 if a condition is true and at 0 otherwise (`w_counter` in my case), and nest this into an outer OLAP query that collects the running sum of that counter (`w_session` in my case). On the way there, I collect the "real" start time of the newly built partition/group. Finally I can group by day of week and newly obtained `session_id`.

```
WITH                                                                                                                                                                                                      
indata(dayofweek,starttime,endtime) AS (
          SELECT 1,61200,62100
UNION ALL SELECT 1,62100,63000
UNION ALL SELECT 1,63000,63900
UNION ALL SELECT 1,63900,64800
UNION ALL SELECT 1,64800,65700
UNION ALL SELECT 1,68800,69900
UNION ALL SELECT 2,51000,52000
)
,
w_counters AS (
SELECT
    *
  , CASE WHEN starttime - LAG(endtime) OVER (PARTITION BY dayofweek ORDER BY starttime) > 0
     THEN starttime
     ELSE MIN(starttime) OVER (PARTITION BY dayofweek)
    END AS daystarttime
  , CASE WHEN starttime - LAG(endtime) OVER (PARTITION BY dayofweek ORDER BY starttime) > 0
     THEN 1
     ELSE 0
    END AS startoverlap
  FROM indata
  -- ctl SELECT * from w_counters ORDER BY 1
  -- ctl  dayofweek | starttime | endtime | daystarttime | ctlstarttime | startoverlap 
  -- ctl -----------+-----------+---------+--------------+--------------+--------------
  -- ctl          1 |     61200 |   62100 |        61200 |        61200 |            0
  -- ctl          1 |     62100 |   63000 |        61200 |        61200 |            0
  -- ctl          1 |     63000 |   63900 |        61200 |        61200 |            0
  -- ctl          1 |     63900 |   64800 |        61200 |        61200 |            0
  -- ctl          1 |     64800 |   65700 |        61200 |        61200 |            0
  -- ctl          1 |     68800 |   69900 |        68800 |        61200 |            1
  -- ctl          2 |     51000 |   52000 |        51000 |        51000 |            0
)
,
w_session AS (
  SELECT
    dayofweek
  , starttime
  , endtime
  , daystarttime
  , SUM(startoverlap) OVER(PARTITION BY dayofweek ORDER BY starttime) AS session_id
  FROM w_counters
  -- ctl ) select * from w_session ORDER BY 1
  -- ctl  dayofweek | starttime | endtime | daystarttime | session_id 
  -- ctl -----------+-----------+---------+--------------+------------
  -- ctl          1 |     61200 |   62100 |        61200 |          0
  -- ctl          1 |     62100 |   63000 |        61200 |          0
  -- ctl          1 |     63000 |   63900 |        61200 |          0
  -- ctl          1 |     63900 |   64800 |        61200 |          0
  -- ctl          1 |     64800 |   65700 |        61200 |          0
  -- ctl          1 |     68800 |   69900 |        68800 |          1
  -- ctl          2 |     51000 |   52000 |        51000 |          0
)
SELECT
  dayofweek
, MIN(daystarttime) AS starttime
, MAX(endtime)      AS endtime
FROM w_session
GROUP BY
  dayofweek
, session_id
ORDER BY
  dayofweek
, session_id
;
-- out  dayofweek | starttime | endtime 
-- out -----------+-----------+---------
-- out          1 |     61200 |   65700
-- out          1 |     68800 |   69900
-- out          2 |     51000 |   52000
```

Comment: Wow that was so quick!  Thank you!  I spent an entire day trying to work that out, Thank you again.

Comment: Re-wrote it.. Did not know it was MS SQL 2014. That DBMS does not support _named windows_ , but they are so handy for readability ....

Comment: I've never seen it before but makes perfect sense, truly thankful.

Comment: Hi again, seems I was too excited to see it last night but these results aren't quite correct.   It's returning the initial minimum starttime as 64800 whereas that should be 61200. Any more ideas out there?

Comment: Oh wow I love the way you worked that out!  It's so clean and concise and logical! I hang my head in shame I was so far off anything like that,  Truly thank you again, I've really learnt from that!